# Is there a way to get matplotlib's Basemap using North Polar Stereographic Projection to plot a range of lat/lons that doesn't include the pole?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, polar-coordinates

Currently, the plot gives me this:

[image]

Using:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# setup north polar stereographic basemap.
# The longitude lon_0 is at 6-o'clock, and the
# latitude circle boundinglat is tangent to the edge
# of the map at lon_0. Default value of lat_ts
# (latitude of true scale) is pole.
m = Basemap(projection='npstere',boundinglat=55,lon_0=-47,resolution='l') #llcrnrlon=-55.,llcrnrlat=60.,urcrnrlon=-40.,urcrnrlat=65.,
#x,y = m(lon2,lat2)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.fillcontinents(color='white',lake_color='aqua')
# draw parallels and meridians.
m.drawparallels(np.arange(-80.,81.,20.))
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180.,181.,20.))
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua')
# draw tissot's indicatrix to show distortion.
ax = plt.gca()
for y in np.linspace(m.ymax/20,19*m.ymax/20,10):
    for x in np.linspace(m.xmax/20,19*m.xmax/20,10):
        lon, lat = m(x,y,inverse=True)
        poly = m.tissot(lon,lat,2.5,100,\
                        facecolor='green',zorder=10,alpha=0.5)
plt.title("North Polar Stereographic Projection")
plt.show()
```

I'd like to be able to zoom in on a part of Greenland particularly, in other words to be able to set the bounding corners of the map to specific latitudes and longitudes. Is this possible? The current projection is too zoomed out.

I'd like something like what this code gives me using Lambert Conformal Conic

```
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-60.,llcrnrlat=60.,urcrnrlon=-40.,urcrnrlat=70.,
            projection='lcc',lat_1=20.,lat_2=40.,lon_0=-60.,
            resolution ='l',area_thresh=1000.)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawcountries()
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#99ffff')
m.fillcontinents(color='#cc9966',lake_color='#99ffff')
m.drawparallels(np.arange(10,70,20),labels=[1,1,0,0])
m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-100,0,20),labels=[0,0,0,1])
plt.title('ICESAT2 Tracks in Greenland')
plt.show()
```

Which gives:

[image]

But in North Polar Stereographic projection of course. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What you asked is not possible with Matplotlib's Basemap. You should start to use `cartopy` in stead. Here is an example that cartopy can plot the map you need.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo(central_longitude=-47))     

ax.set_extent([-55, -42, 59, 70], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

resol = '50m'  # use data at this scale
land = cartopy.feature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'land', \
    scale=resol, edgecolor='k', facecolor=cfeature.COLORS['land'])
ocean = cartopy.feature.NaturalEarthFeature('physical', 'ocean', \
    scale=resol, edgecolor='none', facecolor=cfeature.COLORS['water'])

# plot sequence is important
ax.add_feature(ocean, linewidth=0.2 )
ax.add_feature(land, facecolor='green')

ax.set_title('central_longitude on -47 $^\circ$W')

# for cartopy version 0.18 only
ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, linewidth=0.5, linestyle='--', color='black')

plt.show()
```

Output plot:

[image]